# extrude a ridge with even thickness

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

Okay so what I want to do is use the face in the picture indicated by the black arrow to create a mesh that follows the path indicated by the red arrow so that it creates a 'lip' along the edge of the surface.

I've tried just extruding all the faces in the path, which gets close to what I'd like but that means on either end there is a gap between the surface on either end as shown in picture two.  I can just draw in the remaining vertices, but that means the distance won't be uniform.

So basically, I'm trying to make a lip, like on a counter-top, drawn along the path highlighted.

I hope what I'm trying to accomplish makes sense.

[image: The red arrow indicates the the path and the black arrow indicates the face I'd like to use.]

[image: The black arrow indicates the gaps]

[image: This is before extruding. I have just added faces to either end and then I'll extrude.][image: Now I just have to trim off the excess and it'll be close to what I wanted.]

Comment: On the second image, it seems that you haven't selected that face. Also you could Extrude>Cancel Transform>Scale.

Comment: This probably doesn't have anything to do with the extruding issue, but it looks like your normals are inverted. Try recalculating them by selecting everything and pressing Ctrl N

Comment: @someonewithpc, this would normally work, but Scale>Shift+Z would be better as it would not add to the height of the lip.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if I'm clearly describing the issue.  I realize I didn't select the face, I'm not trying to extrude that face I'm trying...

Comment: Okay well I've come up with a workable solution but it's still not what I'd really want.  So, I was hoping to get the angles of the intersecting boxes to come out from the peaks of each joint evenly, but as it is now they come out along arbitrary (or seemingly arbitrary) angles.  So when you extrude one single face, it's always straight off, but in this case blender has split the difference between the various faces.  I think.  I'll add before and afters of my solution to the original post.  Hopefully that'll shed some light on it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want something like this? http://www.pasteall.org/pic/78669